# Angular 1.4.2 $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-cordova

I tried all the solutions(Stackoverflow,etc..) but none worked for me.
All scripts Were loaded, i using vs 2015, i'm trying to put together a menu.
Mobile angular version 1.2
Angular 1.4.2
i call my function (start in pageteste.js)
Thanks for all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <link href="css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pageteste.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function start() {
            var app = angular.module('AngularUIBucketApp', [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngTouch",
    "mobile-angular-ui"
            ]);

         /*   angular.module('myApp', [
   "ngRoute",
   "mobile-angular-ui",
            ]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    // ...
                });
                // ...
            });*/
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="AngularUIBucketApp">

    // go

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you ever call your `start()` function which initializes your app

Comment: You dont need to owrap your code inside start() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Tom stated you need to actually call your `start()` function.

```
function start() {

  var app = angular.module('AngularUIBucketApp', [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngTouch",
    "mobile-angular-ui"
  ]);   
 } 

 start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I need install Angular.js on Nuget "right button->Manege NugGet Packages"